# Find the sum of all odd numbers between a and b (inclusive), where both a and b are user inputs. My set_1 works but set_2 doesn't - Why?

Tags: java, if-statement, conditional-statements, java.util.scanner, counter

NOTE: Scanner was imported in both sets

in the main method:

start of code set_1...

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for user input
    System.out.print("Enter number, a: "); //prompt for user to enter number for variable, a
    int numA = input.nextInt(); //variable for 1st number, a
    int a = numA; //variable created to track 1st number entered - will be used to print later

    System.out.print("Enter number, b: "); //prompt for user to enter number for variable, b
    int numB = input.nextInt(); //variable for 2nd number, b


    int oddSum = 0; //variable to hold calculation of total odd sum
    //to loop between two numbers
    while (numA <= numB){
        //> 1 for odd #s to enter conditional
        if ((numA % 2) > 0){
            oddSum += numA; //variable, oddSum will store all added numbers between the 2 entered #s
        }
        numA++; //numA is counted +1
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of all odd numbers between " + a + " and " + numB + " is " + oddSum);
```

...end of code set_1 ==> this works 100%

start of code set_2...

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for user input
    System.out.print("Enter number, a: "); //prompt for user to enter number for variable, a
    int numA = input.nextInt(); //variable for 1st number, a                             
    System.out.print("Enter number, b: "); //prompt for user to enter number for variable, b
    int numB = input.nextInt(); //variable for 2nd number, b


    int oddSum = 0; //variable to hold calculation of total odd sum
    int numerBetweenAandB = numA; //variable created to track 1st # entered and count up
    //to loop between two numbers
    while (numA <= numB){
        //> 1 for odd #s to enter conditional
        if ((numA % 2) > 0){
            oddSum += numberBetweenAandB; //variable, will store all added numbers between the 2 #s
        }
        numberBetweenAandB++; // counted +1
    }
    System.out.println("The sum of all odd numbers between " + numA + " and " + numB + " is " + oddSum);
```

...end of code set_2 ==> this goes into an infinite loop.Why?

what is wrong w/ my logic here? As I understand it - the 1st number is stored in numberbetweenAandB and this goes up using the ++ counter until the loop ends by which time variable oddSum has added all the #s between a and b.

Appreciate your time and effort looking in to this. I'm still learning.

Comment: In your `while (numA <= numB)` loop you're not updating `numA` or `numB`. So there's no way for the loop to end.

Comment: Thank you. appreciate the clarification. Very obvious as I see it now.

Answer (score 0):

in your code, you have:

```
while (numA <= numB){
  // a bunch of code; and none of it changes numA or numB
}
```

obviously then, if this while loop enters even once, it will enter forever; numA and numB do not change, thus if it's true at the beginning, it will be true forever.

Comment: Thank you. appreciate the clarification. Very obvious as I see it now.